# Create virtual folder in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, projects-and-solutions

Essentially I need a folder and its items available in the project for debugging but I don't want it included in the publish.

Comment: please elaborate on that... especially `its items`

Comment: Folder(s) generally stores images/documents.  Project goes out to several clients who each store relevant images/documents in different places so virtual folders are created in IIS to accomodate. I currently have folders/files in project and delete from publish directory but want to skip this step and simply not output them.  There are hundreds in some of these folders so don't want to select each one and change Build to none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude folders from your build-Solution (by default Debug and Publish are available).

- Right click in the solution explorer and `Add New Folder`. Name it.
- Right click on the folder and choose '`Exclude from project`'

[image: Excluding a Folder from a Project/Solution]

Note the screenshot is from VS2010 C# Express, but the same option is available in VS2012.

Comment: To clarify this will keep it available when debugging?

Comment: It will be specifically excluded from compilation, but available to you through the IDE. This method allows rapid switching of project code-resources through several 'solution'-builds such as the common `'Debug'-Solution`.